If already started Bitcoin Core using the daemon, and I'm in IBD, if I stop it to start it up again through the GUI, will I run into any issues?
Issues like having to restart the IBD, or messing up its download. Or would stopping it be the wrong approach to configuring the GUI?
Additionally, is there a way to use the daemon to check on the progress of the IBD?

Hey CoinZwischenzug, thanks for your questions here! One note for future questions: please try to ask only about one topic, so topics can be more easily searched by other readers of this archive. In this case, "How can I check on progress of the IBD? would have been great as a separate question.

IBD does not need to be done in one session. Bitcoin Core saves its progress as it goes, and when shutdown cleanly, on shutdown. It will resume where it left off on the next start.

Additionally, is there a way to use the daemon to check on the progress of the IBD?

You can use the getblockchaininfo RPC which will tell you the current height and hash, whether the node is IBD state, and the estimated progress, among other info.
